How can I calculate responsive web design
This is my intro.css:
#intro {
    height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -4rem;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
    height:  100vh;
}

.introContent {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hello {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.introName {
    color: yellow;
}

.introPara {
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 200;

}

.btn {
    background: white;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2rem;
}

.btnImg {
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:840px) {
    .bg {
        right: -10vw;
    }
    .introContent {
        font-size: 10vw;
    }
    .hello {
        font-size: 4.5vw;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .bg {
        right: -20vw;
    }

}

Sadly, it looks weird at 3840x2160 display resolution. The left and right margins are huge.
I'm following this YouTube video but I cannot get it to work the way I want.

You have a max-width of 75rem on #intro. Assuming a normal sort of rem size of 16px this comes to 1200px, which on the screen you describe leaves (3840 - 1200) px to be shared between the left and right margins - which is as you say quite a lot. Is there a reason you have limited the width to 75rem?
